# Smoothing out a jQueryUI switchClass() transition (currently jerky)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I'm having an issue with my slider that makes it look somewhat awkward and not very smooth. I am using the latest jQuery and jQueryUI.

Here's my slider:

http://samstil.es/slider.html

If you look closely at the food as they move around (particularly when transitioning to & from the being the centre image) you can see that they "shrink" vertically for a brief second resting at their appropriate size.

I guess my question is: does anybody know how I can make the transition smoother, so you don't notice any jerkiness?

Here's the code, JavaScript first:

```
<script>

    String.prototype.insert = function (index, string) {
        if (index > 0) {
            return this.substring(0, index) + string + this.substring(index, this.length);
        } else {
            return string + this;
        }
    };

    function activateImage(i) {
        var oldSrc = $('.pos' + i).attr('src');
        var positionOfPNG = oldSrc.indexOf(".png");
        var newSrc = oldSrc.insert(positionOfPNG, "-active");
        $('.pos' + i).attr('src', newSrc);
    };

    function deactivateImage(i) {
        var oldSrc = $('.pos' + i).attr('src');
        var newSrc = oldSrc.replace('-active','');
        $('.pos' + i).attr('src', newSrc);
    };

    function moveImageRightOne(i) {
        if ( i == 5 ) {
            $('.pos5').switchClass('pos5', 'pos1', 400, "swing");
        } else {
            $('.pos' + i).switchClass('pos' + i, 'pos' + (i + 1), 400, "swing");
        }

        if ( i == 2 ) {
            activateImage(i);
        }

        if ( i == 3 ) {
            deactivateImage(i);
        }
    };

    function moveImageLeftOne(i) {
        if ( i == 1 ) {
            $('.pos1').switchClass('pos1', 'pos5', 400, "swing");
        } else {
            $('.pos' + i).switchClass('pos' + i, 'pos' + (i - 1), 400, "swing");
        }

        if ( i == 4 ) {
            activateImage(i);
        }

        if ( i == 3 ) {
            deactivateImage(i);
        }
    };

    function slideRight() {
        var sliderLength = $('#foodCarousel img').length;
        for (var i = 1; i < sliderLength + 1; i++) {
            moveImageRightOne(i);
        }
    };

    function slideLeft() {
        var sliderLength = $('#foodCarousel img').length;
        for (var i = 1; i < sliderLength + 1; i++ ) {
            moveImageLeftOne(i);
        }
    };

</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    #foodCarousel {
        width: 970px;
        height: 160px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    #foodCarousel img {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .pos1 {
        z-index: 5;
        top:15px;
        left: 50px;
        max-height: 75px;
        max-width: 75px;
    }

    .pos2 {
        z-index: 10;
        top:50px;
        left: 200px;
        max-height: 125px;
        max-width: 125px;
    }

    .pos3 {
        z-index: 99999;
        top:25px;
        left: 400px;
        max-height: 150px;
        max-width: 150px;
    }

    .pos4 {
        z-index: 10;
        top: 35px;
        left: 650px;
        max-height: 125px;
        max-width: 125px;
    }

    .pos5 {
        z-index: 5;
        top:15px;
        left: 850px;
        max-height: 75px;
        max-width: 75px;
    }


</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foodCarousel">
    <img class="pos1" src="/img/food7.png" alt="Corn">
    <img class="pos2" src="/img/food18.png" alt="Sesame Seed">
    <img class="pos3" src="/img/food11.png" alt="Meat">
    <img class="pos4" src="/img/food4.png" alt="Apple">
    <img class="pos5" src="/img/food3.png" alt="Blueberry">
</div>

<button style="margin-left:300px;" onclick="slideLeft()"><-- left</button>
<button onclick="slideRight()">right --></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it looks like this behavior is occuring because of the different sizes of the full sized images.

I noticed by scrolling through that the jerk didn't happen on the grapes, so I set a min-width and height equal to that size on the largest element.  Seemed to do the trick.

```
#foodCarousel img.pos3 {
    min-width:150px;
    min-height:111px;
}
```